# How to zoom div on hover in percent

Tags: html, css

i want that the zoom-in will effect only the img inside the div and won't resize all the div scale

here is the fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/4tHWg/1/

example code:

```
.box {
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   width: 14.285714286%;



}

.boxInner img {
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(00%);
   -moz-filter: grayscale(00%);
   -o-filter: grayscale(00%);
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
   -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
      transition: all 1s ease;

}

.boxInner img:hover {
  width: 200%;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use css transforms:

http://jsfiddle.net/4tHWg/3/

```
.boxInner img:hover {      
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
  -o-transform: scale(1.4);
  transform: scale(1.4);    
}
```

1.4 equals 1.4 times its original size.

Comment: i want the effect will heppened inside a div and not scale the whole div

Comment: it does not scale the whole div. You can see this, if you apply an outline to both elements. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: ummm i want that the div that "wrap" the scale effect will stay his original size and the scale will heppened only inside the div

Comment: it does not scale up. check out the fiddle please.

Comment: @alonblack Please stop making assumptions until you check Hugo's answer out. I endorse/+1 his solution (because it is the way it should work). Scaling a child has nothing to do with the parent's dimension.

Comment: Unless the parent has no size set. If the solution is not working, set the parent max-width/max-height to not go beyond the intended area

Comment: @AndréLucas actually i can't reproduce this behavior. which browser are you using?

Comment: It will only works in modern browser, but the css transform also would only do so there. Chrome is my quick answer. I suggest trying a similar solution with javascript if the desired effect is not being achieved with CSS only. :)

Comment: @AndréLucas  I can't reconstruct this behavior in the current version of chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to hugo's answer, you should add this to your parent element.

```
.boxInner {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.boxInner img:hover {      
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
   -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
   -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
   -o-transform: scale(1.4);
   transform: scale(1.4);    
}
```

This way the div won't resize together with the child image.